# Google Colab conda packages permanently installation

Tags: anaconda, google, colab, pip

I want to install some conda packages on Google Colab. Installation done successfully, but it wont detect it when we restart the new Colab session.

I followed the link "#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab", but still no luck.

Please let me know how to install python packages using conda + pip permanently on Google Colab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to permanently install packages because the code is run on virtual machines that are sometimes recycled. You'll need to install it each time.

From the [FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html):

> Where is my code executed? What happens to my execution state if I close the browser window?
> Code is executed in a virtual machine dedicated to your account. Virtual machines are recycled when idle for a while, and have a maximum lifetime enforced by the system.